# javascript foreach in a matrix

Tags: javascript, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have a matrix consisting in 0s, 1s and an "X" and I'm trying to use the "forEach()" method in order to find the "X" and replace it with another value. How would I exactly do that?

```
let a=new Array
for(int i=0;i<=5;i++) {
  a[i]=new Array
  for(int j=0;j<=5;j++) {
    a[i][j]=Math.round(Math.random())
  }
}
a[3][2]="X" //the indexes are random values

for(int i=0;i<=5;i++) {
  for(int j=0;i<=5;j++) {
    if(a[i][j]=="X") {
      a[i][j]="found"
      break
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you provide a sample matrix and also show what you've tried?

Comment: I have edited my original post. What I want to do is get rid of the 3rd and 4th for loops and search the "X" element by using the "forEach()" method.

Comment: okay. and what have you tried to use `forEach`? and - if I might ask - whats the reason to use `forEach`?

Comment: a.forEach(function(element) {
      if(element=="X") element="found"
    })

Comment: well I think it is more efficient and it looks cleaner, plus the fact that I'm trying to learn to use as many methods in this project that I'm currently working on.

Answer (score 0):

```
let matrix1 = [
[0, 1, 0, 1, 1],
[1, 0, 1, 1, 1],
[0, 1, 1, 0, 0],
[1, 0, 1, 0, 1],
[0, 1, 1, 'x', 1]
];

matrix1
    .forEach((element1, index1, array1) => { 
        element1.forEach((element2, index2, array2) => {
            if(array1[index1][index2] == 'x') {
                array1[index1][index2] = 'y';
            }
        });
    });
```

There may be other (and better solutions), but this should work. But I would recommend to stay with the two nested-for-loops.
For the `forEach` approach two lambda-functions have to be created and when they are called a context-switch happens (not sure about that, might be optimized/removed by the javascript interpreter). So the memory-footprint might be slightly higher and the performance probably lower. But for a 5x5 matrix nothing of that is important.
Plain for loops are also much more readable - at least for me ;)

Comment: @AndreiPriboi if the answer helped you or solved your problem, please *accept* the answer to show that the question is solved

Answer (score 0):

Instead of doing it with forEach, I would be using for-of loop.

```
let matrix = [
  [0, 1, 0, "x", 1],
  [1, 0, 1, 1, 1],
  [0, "x", 1, 0, 0],
  ["x", 0, 1, 0, 1],
  [0, 1, 1, 0, 1]
];

for (const [i, row] of matrix.entries()) {
  for (const [j, element] of row.entries()) {
    if (element === "x") {
      matrix[i][j] = "Boom";
    }
  }
}
```

Final, output would be:

```
[
  [0, 1, 0, "Boom", 1],
  [1, 0, 1, 1, 1],
  [0, "Boom", 1, 0, 0],
  ["Boom", 0, 1, 0, 1],
  [0, 1, 1, 0, 1]
]
```

Comment: @AndreiPriboi, I would suggest you to go through this approach because In terms of performance, Traditional for loops are much more efficient than any of the array loop method such as forEach or map.